# Разница между инициализацией

Tags: c++

Есть ли разница между

```
vector<int> v (istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>());
```

и

```
vector<int> v;
copy (istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(v));
```

?

Answer (score 5):

Первый вариант предпочтительнее, т.к. он более лаконичен и позволяет объявить объект константным.

---

Однако, чтобы он работал ожидаемым образом, следует заменить круглые скобки на фигурные:

```
vector<int> v {istream_iterator<int>(cin),istream_iterator<int>()};
```

Иначе, исходная конструкция будет интерпретирована компилятором как объявление функции `v`, принимающей 2 аргумента (один типа `istream_iterator<int>` с именем `cin`, второй - безымянный указатель на функцию без аргументов, возвращающую `istream_iterator<int>`) и возвращающей `vector<int>`. Более подробно о том, почему так происходит можно почитать например в вики на странице [`most vexing parse`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

---

С учетом исправления синтаксиса, разницы в конечном результате нет. Но зачем делать сложнее, когда можно проще?

Answer (score 0):

В принципе, разница не велика, результат один и тот же. Просто в первом случае вызывается конструктор копирования, а во втором случае сначала вызывается стандартный конструктор, затем уже происходит копирование.

Comment: Вызова копирующего конструктора тут нет, равно как и понятия "стандартный конструктор".