# Разница между инициализацией 2

Tags: c++

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iterator>

 int main()
 {
    std::ifstream fi;
    std::vector<int> ve(std::istream_iterator<int>(fi),std::istream_iterator<int>());
    ve.begin();
 }
```

Пишет ошибку:

> [Error] request for member 'begin' in 've', which is of non-class type
>   'std::vector(std::istream_iterator,
>   std::istream_iterator (*)())'

Если написать так, то всё нормально:

```
 #include <fstream>
 #include <vector>
 #include <iterator>
 #include <algorithm>

 int main()
 {
    std::ifstream fi;
    std::vector<int> ve;
    copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(fi),std::istream_iterator<int>(),back_inserter(ve));
    ve.begin();
 }
```

А [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509052/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9) сказали, что разницы нет. Так в чём проблема?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Я бы все же применил инициализацию в фигурных скобках.

```
std::vector<int> ve{std::istream_iterator<int>(fi),std::istream_iterator<int>()};
```

Это будет 100% инициализация, а пока проблема в том, что `ve` компилятор воспринимает как объявление функции.

Comment: Почему?????????

Comment: Это будет 100% инициализация, а пока, похоже, проблема в том, что `ve` компилятор воспринимает как функцию. Почему - я пока сам разбираюсь :)

Comment: @abvgd см. дополненный ответ в другой [теме](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/509052/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%B9). P.S. И зачем заводить нового пользователя на каждый вопрос?

Comment: @alexolut в том то и дело, что с потоком `std::cin` всё нормально работает без всяких круглых скобок и `{}`, а вот с файловым нужно извращаться

Comment: @alexolut Спасибо, а то я четко понимал "что", ссылка на Most vexing parse прояснила, почему.

Comment: И ещё: что по эффективности лучше - через `{}` или дополнительные `()`?

Comment: @abvgd А это совершенно неважно - это не для вызова, а для разрешения неоднозначности. Мне больше нравятся фигурные скобки, потому что, на мой взгляд, яснее указывают намерение - вызов конструктора.

Comment: @Harry у вас с потоком `std::cin` ошибка возникает? или только с `std::istream_iterator<int>(fi)`?

Comment: Да, точно так же. Правда, у меня VC++ 2015.

Comment: Используйте фигурные скобки для вызова конструктора. class_name() компилятор может распознать как указатель на функцию, возвращающий объект типа class_name.

Answer (score 2):

Очевидно, что *ve.begin();* в обоих случаях должен быть верным. Проблема в строке выше, в объявление *ve* неправильное. Xcode выводит такое пояснение:

> Parentheses were disambiguated as a function declaration

Дополнительные скобки избавляют компилятор от неоднозначности и решают проблему:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::ifstream fi;
    std::vector<int> ve((std::istream_iterator<int>(fi)), std::istream_iterator<int>());
    ve.begin();
}
```

Comment: Ничего себе! Так а в чём неоднозначность заключается?

Comment: И почему, если написать вместо `fi` `std::cin`, такого не происходит?

Comment: Привёл ведь в ответе комментарий от Xcode: компилятор где-то в строке находит объявление функции. Если один из аргументов охватить скобками, то ему станет ясно понятно, что там перечислены переменные.

Comment: @abvgd у меня с std::cin ошибка не исчезает, только скобки помогают. Что в принципе и логично.

Comment: Для одного потока он понимает сразу, а для другого нужно "помогать"? Это ведь стандартный конструктор вектора...

Comment: Какой у вас компилятор?

Comment: GNU++11, а у вас? И как уже написал, у меня для всех потоков такая неоднозначность возникает.

Comment: GCC, вот такие 2 строки с подключенным `iostream` не вызывают ошибку:`std::vector<int> ve(std::istream_iterator<int>(std::cin),std::istream_iterator<int>());
  ve.begin();`